# Ruby on rails: Select table multiple rows and calculate sum after that add result to another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new in ror. I'm learning Active Record Query Interface in here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/active_record_querying.html

I followed steps above documentation, but couldn't success. I need help.

Here is the Mysql command:

```
SELECT sum(amount), member_id, order_id
FROM (
    SELECT sum(amount) as amount, o_member_id as member_id, order_id
    FROM `orders`
    WHERE created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND o_member_id NOT IN (1, 2) 
    GROUP BY o_member_id, order_id 
    UNION ALL SELECT sum(amount) as amount, o2_member_id as member_id, order_id 
    FROM `orders`
    WHERE created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND o2_member_id NOT IN (1, 2)
    GROUP BY o2_member_id, order_id
) as t1 GROUP BY order_id, member_id;
```

This mysql query returns following informations:

| sum(amount) | order_id | member_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1324.1125122 | pc_laptop | 1 |
| 1324.1125122 | home_tv | 1 |
| 1324.1125122 | pc_laptop | 3 |

So i will took above informations and add the table below:

| id | member_id | order_id | amount | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bigint | int | varchar | decimal | datetime | datetime |

I really appriciate any hints and help.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail exactly what data you are trying to pull.

Comment: @bryanfeller Hi, i updated code.

Comment: I see your query is working fine. What's issue with saving the data? You have not included anything rails related.

Comment: @Alex I couldnt write mysql query in rails. I need help for it. So how can i write similar query in rails?

Comment: @suakinos can I see how you set up your models?